# custom Filter and apply Char index in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to apply filtering logic and also searching from specific string in a column but unable to figure it out.

here is the sample script below:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test](
    service_id int,
    category_id int,
    employee_name varchar(50)
    )

insert into Test values (38756,201830,'kalyan');
insert into Test values (38366,201790,'kalyan');
insert into Test values (38756,201830,'kalyan');
insert into Test values (38366,201790,'kalyan');

CREATE TABLE [major](
spec_id int,
manager_name varchar(150)
)

insert into major values (38756,null);
insert into major values (38366,null);
insert into major values (38756,'Express Door for on going : DECLINE by kalyan');
insert into major values (38366,'Express door for on going : APPROVE by Joy kalyan')\
insert into major values (38366,'Request required');
```

**Query I tried:**

```
select distinct service_id, 
category_id, 
employee_name,
case when manager_name like 'Express Door%' then manager_name
     when manager_name like 'Express door%' then manager_name end as manager
  from Test
left join major on spec_id = service_id and manager_name is not null
```

**My expected output should be like this ((get value after string (by) in the manager field)**

```
service_id  category_id   employee_name        manager
38366         201790         kalyan            Joy kalyan
38756         201830         kalyan            kalyan
```

Thanks in advance
Swetha J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SQL> select distinct
  2    t.service_id,
  3    t.category_id,
  4    t.employee_name,
  5    substr(m.manager_name, instr(m.manager_name, 'by') + 3) manager
  6  from test t join major m on m.spec_id = t.service_id
  7  where instr(m.manager_name, 'by') > 0;

SERVICE_ID CATEGORY_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME        MANAGER
---------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------
     38366      201790 kalyan               Joy kalyan
     38756      201830 kalyan               kalyan

SQL>
```